# DD and Free Space

Tags: filesystems, dd

I have a partition (/dev/sda1) of 10 GB. Also have "dd" file of another 7 GB partition ( /dev/sdb1).

When I execute the command as:

> dd if=sdb1.dd of=/dev/sda1

then everything goes fine but I can not use remaining 3 GB space of /dev/sda1

Is there any way to tell DD to utilize remaining free space ( 3 GB in this case ) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dd` does not care about free space (as in the filesystem concept) whatsoever, it just copies block by block.

If `sdb1.dd` is a filesystem image, you may be able to grow it using `resize2fs` or other tools (depending on the filesystem type) after you copied it.

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tell DD to utilize remaining free space ( 3 GB in this case ) ?

No.

More to the point, assuming the target partition is the proper size (as you say), what you are doing is effectively writing a file system which only knows about the first portion of the partition. `dd` does not care about the meaning of the data written either at the source or the destination.

Depending on the file system in use, you might be able to *expand the file system* to use the entire partition, but that's far beyond the responsibilities of `dd` and the specifics will depend heavily on which exact file system is inside that image file.

Answer (score 0):

dd doesn't copy files, if copies bytes.  That includes the structure of the filesystem, which is a 7 gigabyte filesystem.  When you are done copying, the filesystem data indicates it is a 7 gigabyte filesystem.

If you are just trying to duplicate all the files, using dd to make a copy isn't what you want.  Use tar, or dump/restore onto a freshly created filesystem.