# Will adding data to a hdd that already has data on it using the "dd" command overwrite the pre-existing data?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, dd

Will adding data to a hdd that already has data on it, by using the "dd" command, overwrite that pre-existing data? I do NOT want to overwrite any data. Data is being copied over from 1 hdd to another one, both of which do not have an OS and only have 1 partition each.

DD COMMAND (example from article):

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1
```

The dd command is for copying over an entire partition, which is what I want to do. This commands seems to be what I need, though I am not sure what to use for "of". The partition name is NOT an 'sdxx', but rather just a name I gave it when encrypting the partition. Lsblk shows "sdx",  and then "ABC" for the partition name.

I imagine I would use

```
"dd if=/dev/sdXX of=/dev/ABC"
```

since the partition name is "ABC".

**UPDATE**: I changed the dd command I would use to copy partition on hdd1 to partition on hdd2. In the dd command, I don't know if I need to use "bs=#" or not.

**source**: #4 from - https://tecadmin.net/drive-and-partition-backup-examples-with-dd-command/
Thanks.

Comment: You would need to provide the `dd` command in question for someone to answer that. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Disk is always full of data. But obviously you're not always interested in all of them. So you can't "add" data to disk, you just become interested in more data region

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I am interested in keeping all of the data and there is enough room to add all the data from the other hdd, so it appears. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer to the question in the subject: yes, if the `of` argument refers to a disk partition , the `dd` command will overwrite the existing data on the partition.

Comment: @JohanMyréen What if I dd the data to a blank hdd and then copy and paste that data to a 3rd hdd (which is encrypted and has previous data). Will the 3rd hdd have the files in byte-by-byte format? Thanks.

Comment: @topencrypt You will have to copy the data as files to the destination file system. That's the only way to preserve the integrity of the file system.

Comment: @JohanMyréen So, I need to dd to the destination file system? When you say "copy the data as files to the destination filesystem, I'm not sure if you mean I need to copy each individual file or something else other than, possibly, dd to final destination. Thanks.

Comment: @topencrypt If you have existing files on the target partition, then you will have to copy the individual files to the partition. You can of course create a tar or zip archive of the files, the contents of which you can then extract where you want.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for dd says:

```
  of=FILE    write to FILE instead of stdout
```

Now you *can* use a special file for output. A block device like /dev/sda (a whole "disk") or /dev/sdaN (a partition). `dd` will in any case fill i.e. **overwrite** your terminal/stdout, your file or your partition.

The way to control this would be the `seek=` operand, to skip an amount of output blocks. But you should not use a partition like a tape drive!

The Example #4 you linked nicely shows the "subtle" difference between /dev/sda and /dev/sda1. Otherwise this link is just a basic demo of the `dd` command. You can "backup" or "clone" a "hdd" with `dd`, but you can not easily "add data".

But to write to an encrypted partition with `dd`? How does that work?

Yes, `bs=1M` should be much faster.

I add this old Q:
[DD and Free Space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92964/dd-and-free-space)